# QGis Essen Node editing slow

Tags: qgis, editing, nodes

We have just set up QGis 2.14 (Essen) in our Corporate Environment.  It is working well, except that editing nodes seems to be extremely slow and in some cases, unusable.  This is when editing SQL 2008 R2 Polygons or Spatiallite polygons in a networked environment.

Saving project files seems to have been greatly sped up, but node editing is definitely far slower, so much so that we are considering whether to roll back to 2.8.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report/feature request rather than a question for Q&A.

Comment: @HarryB Did you try with the latest version of QGIS 2.18.1? Companies usually prefer to stick to LTS but since you're just migrating you could probably just as well install this new version.

Comment: Hello and No, we haven't tried that yet, will do so.  I am doing some further testing in relation to our networked environment because it doesn't seem to be an issue when files are held locally.  I am not convinced it is actually a bug as such, which is why it is in Q&A because I would value any advice people might be able to give me.